# Can the residue of a function at a point be complex?

Tags: complex-integration, residue-calculus

Consider the following attempt to calculate $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{1+x^4} \, dx$:

First we note that $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{1+x^4}$ is even, so $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{1+x^4} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{1+x^4} \, dx $$

Next, consider that $$\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}  = \frac{x^2}{(x-i)(x+i)(x-1)(x+1)}$$ and so $f(x)$ has 4 simple poles.

Then to find the residues, we are allowed to take \begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to i}{(x-i)f(x)} &= \lim_{x \to i} \frac{(x-i)x^2}{(x-i)(x+i)(x-1)(x+1)} = \frac{i^2}{(2i)(i^2-1)} = \frac{-1}{2i^3-2i} \\
\lim_{x \to -i}{(x+i) f(x)} &= \dots \\
\lim_{x \to -1}{(x+1) f(x)} &= \dots \\
\lim_{x \to  1}{(x-1) f(x)} &= \dots
\end{align*}

But I'm noticing that when I do this, I am getting complex residues; I don't believe I've ever obtained complex residues before. Although, at the same time, I couldn't see why the residues couldn't be complex. Is this okay or have I made an error somewhere? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having complex residues is completely okay (since they will hopefully sum to something purely imaginary). However your factorization of the denominator is incorrect

Comment: @NinadMunshi Oh I see. Let me make sure then. $x^4+1 = 0 \implies x^4 = -1 \implies x = \pm \sqrt{i}$ correct?

Comment: I don't know the works of the residue theorem very well, but I would imagine complex residues would be common? Especially since returning to the real line requires multiplying by $2 \pi i$. I'm highly uncertain about that. However, I'm very certain about this: your first residue simplifies further to $1/4i$. The other three simplify to $-1/4i, -1/4, 1/4$, respectively. Perhaps those simpler expressions help?

Comment: @cheesefoot yep those are correct, however you should probably represent them differently, like in polar form.